# Chain DNS lookups for "not found" answer/events

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, lookup

Im trying to chain multiple dns server.

I want that my local dns server is asked first, if no entry was found a second and third should be asked.

Is this possible?

My `/etc/resolve.conf` looks like this:

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search fritz.box
```

For my understanding, even if there are other dns server listed (not sure how this is handeld with systemd-resolved), only the first one is asked.
When the first one does not answer (offline/timeout) the second is asked, but not if the first one response with "not found".

How is it possible to build a chain on "not found" events/answers?

Backround, i want to access my local machines via their names.
But when i work and connect via vpn, i need also be able to resolve corporates names.
Both on the same time.

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT: I forgot that i have a pihole running. With this solution it would break my adblocking. Is there a way to practices this nested lookup only for specific domains? Likes, everything goes to my pihole, execpt: *.example.com?